# Node.js: How to stop a pipe from streaming data

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm creating a request using the request npm module. However in case the content type is not json, i want the stream to stop. At the moment, it does not stop and and error is generated because unzip reads an invalid header.. **How can we stop a stream?**

```
    var req = request(options)
    req
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log("err"); reject(err) })
    .on('response', function(response) { 

        if(response.headers['content-type'] != 'application/json')
        {
            console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
            req.destroy() // doesn't work
            this.destroy() // doesn't work
        }
    })
    .on('end', function () { resolve() })

    .pipe(gunzip)  // ERROR!
```

Comment: Are this code logging the response.headers['content-type'] in the if statement?

Comment: Have you tried `response.end()` or `req.end()` instead?

Comment: response.end() is not a function and req.end() does not work

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva yes it logs whenever it is not json

Comment: I think you can throw an error nested in if statement so.

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva when I throw an error inside the if-statement, I cannot catch it by surrounding the whole piping inside a try catch block. When the error is thrown, the program stops

Comment: Ah yes, in fact, the req.on('error') just will catch a request error, not a response. My mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [stream.pause()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) as follows:

```
var req = request(options)
req
  .on('error', function (err) { console.log("err"); reject(err) })
  .on('response', function(response) { 

    if(response.headers['content-type'] != 'application/json')
    {
        console.log(response.headers['content-type'])

        req.pause(); // stream paused
        reject('not json');
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () { resolve() })
  .pipe(gunzip)
```